# If $f$,$g$ (not necessarily differentiable) are convex, non-negative, and increasing on $(a,b)$, then $f \cdot g$ is also convex on $(a,b)$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The question is in the title. Show that $f\cdot g$ is convex on $(a,b)$, provided that $f, g$ are non-negative, increasing, and convex on $(a,b)$. I know that if $f,g$ are differentiable, then I can simply show that $(f\cdot g)'' >0$ on the interval, but in this case differentiability is not specified. I tried to answer it by simply multiplying the inequalities that result from the definition
$$
h(tx+(1-t)y)\leq th(x) + (1-t)h(y)
$$
for $h=f$, $h=g$ and $t \in [0,1]$, but I couldn't really get anywhere with it. I know there is a question on here about this before, but all of the answers there relating to this specific case assumed differentiability, and in my case the question does not say that the functions are differentiable. I would appreciate any guidance on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial answer that does not use differentiability but also does not use the non-negativity of $f$ and $g$. Let $x,y\in(a,b)$ and assume wlog that $x\leq y$ and let also $t\in[0,1]$. Then,
\begin{align*} h(tx+(1-t)y)&=f(tx+(1-t)y)\cdot g(tx+(1-t)y) \\ &\leq[tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)]\cdot[tg(x)+(1-t)g(y)] \\ &=t^{2}(fg)(x)+t(1-t)f(x)g(y)+t(1-t)f(y)g(x)+(1-t)^{2}(fg)(y) \\ &\leq t^{2}(fg)(x)+t(1-t)(fg)(y)+t(1-t)(fg)(y) +(1-t)^{2}(fg)(y) \\ &= t^{2}(fg)(x)+(fg)(y)[(1-t)^{2}+2t(1-t)] \\ &=t^{2}(fg)(x)+(1-t^{2})(fg)(y)=t^{2}h(x)+(1-t^{2})h(y) \end{align*}
where the first inequality uses the convexity of $f$ and $g$, and where the second inequality uses the fact that both $f$ and $g$ are increasing.